# Timespan difference not calculating correctly

Tags: c#, webforms, timespan

I am building a web form in C#.  I have 3 drops downs for Start Time (Start Hour, Start Minute, and Start Time of Day (AM or PM) and 3 for finish time.  My goal is to calculate the difference.  Everything works fine until I choose noon or midnight.  When I choose noon and debug, the value shows as 1.  Here is my code.

```
var startHourDDL = ddlStartHour.SelectedValue;
var startMinuteDDL = ddlStartMinute.SelectedValue;
var startTOD = ddlStartTOD.SelectedValue;

int startHour = Convert.ToInt32(startHourDDL);
int startMinute = Convert.ToInt32(startMinuteDDL);

var finishHourDDL = ddlFinishHour.SelectedValue;
var finishMinuteDDL = ddlFinishMinute.SelectedValue;
var finishTOD = ddlFinishTOD.SelectedValue;

int finishHour = Convert.ToInt32(finishHourDDL);
int finishMinute = Convert.ToInt32(finishMinuteDDL);

if (startTOD == "PM")
{
    startTime = new TimeSpan(startHour + 12, startMinute, 0);
}

else
{
    startTime = new TimeSpan(startHour, startMinute, 0);
}

if (finishTOD == "PM")
{
    finishTime = new TimeSpan(finishHour + 12, finishMinute, 0);
}

else
{
    finishTime = new TimeSpan(finishHour, finishMinute, 0);
}

TimeSpan diff = finishTime - startTime;
string time = String.Format(diff.Hours + " Hours, " + diff.Minutes + " Minutes");

lblDurAmount.Text = time;
```

So if I choose 2:00 PM for start time and 4:00 PM for finish time, the label shows 2 hours.  However, if I choose 12:00 PM for start time and 2:00 PM for finish time I get -10 hours.

This is what I get for start time when I debug at 12:00 PM.

```
{1.00:00:00}
```

Here is what I get when I choose 5:00 PM

```
{17:00:00}
```

I can't figure out why it won't set noon to 24.  I even tried adding an if statement

```
if (startHour == 12 && startTOD)
{
    startTime = new TimeSpan(24, startMinute, 0);
}
```

But that didn't work either.  Value was still 1.00.

Comment: Why are you using `TimeSpan` to store dates (e.g. `finishTime`)?

Comment: 12PM without any other context comes after 2PM so when you subtract 2PM - 12PM you get -10hours. You need to check if startTime is after finishTime and swap the two values if true.

Comment: @mjwillis.  No real reason.  I was dealing with TimeSpans so I made all TimeSpans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `TimeSpan` is for storing a duration of time, not a time during the day.

As such, while you believe you are storing "12PM", what you are actually storing is a 24 hour time period. And "2PM" is a 14 hour time period.

Thus "2PM" - "12PM" = 14 hours - 24 hours (i.e. -10 hours).

To solve this, you need to store date/time in `DateTime`, not `TimeSpan`.

Comment: Ah ok.  That makes sense.  So for noon, could you just set it to 12 and for midnight set to 24?  Or would it be easier in the long run to just ditch the TimeSpans?

Comment: It would be easier to choose a datatype that reflects the underlying concept. `TimeSpan` is not for storing a point in time (it is for storing duration). Can you make it work using `TimeSpan` rather than `DateTime`? Sure. Will it be hard to understand and maintain? Definitely.

Comment: Good point.  Thank you for the help.  I will convert my timespans to date time and then handle noon and midnight separately

Answer (score 1):

Your operations works only if the startTime is less than the finishTime otherwise all the results will come back as negatives. In your example 12 PM   comes after 2 PM so when you subtract 2 PM - 12 PM you get then -10 hours.
You need to check if startTime is after finishTime and swap the two values if true

```
if (finishTime < startTime)
{
    TimeSpan swap = finishTime;
    finishTime = startTime;
    startTime = swap;
}
TimeSpan diff = finishTime - startTime;
string time = String.Format(diff.TotalHours + " Hours, " + diff.Minutes + " Minutes");
```

Comment: Same comment as other answer.  Would it work to just set 2 more if statements and set noon to 12 and midnight to 0?